# Не отображаются поля для ввода (динамическая форма) C# MVC

Tags: c#, html5, asp.net-mvc, razor

Помогите решить проблему с отображением формы ввода данных. При загрузке страницы Create.cshtml пользователю должны быть сразу доступны все поля для ввода значений, и если пользователь хочет добавить еще одно поле Email/Adress/Phone, то он нажимает на кнопку "Добавить", js добавляет еще одно поле. Так вот в том виде, как у меня сейчас реализовано, по кнопке "Добавить" поля добавляются, а при изначальной загрузке страницы поле для ввода отсутствует, но отображается кнопка "Добавить".

[image: Форма добавления записи]

View:

```
    <div class="form-horizontal">
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Active, true)
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Notes, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Notes, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Notes, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Телефон", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div id="phoneList">
                @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Phones.Count; i++)
                {
                    <div class="phoneRow">
                        @Html.DropDownList("Phones[" + i + "].Type", Model.Phones[i].PhoneTypeSelectListItems, new { @class = "phoneType form-control" })
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.Phones[i].Value, new { placeholder = "Номер телефона", @class = "phoneNumber form-control" })
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remRowPhone"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>Удалить</a>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
            <p>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="addRowPhone"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>Добавить номер</a>
            </p>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phones, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Email", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div id="emailList">
                @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Emails.Count; i++)
                {
                    <div class="emailRow">
                        @Html.DropDownList("Emails[" + i + "].Type", Model.Emails[i].EmailTypeSelectListItems, new { @class = "emailType form-control" })
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.Emails[i].Value, new { placeholder = "Электропочта", @class = "emailValue form-control" })
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remRowEmail"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>Удалить</a>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
            <p>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="addRowEmail"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>Добавить Email</a>
            </p>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Emails, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Адрес", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div id="addressList">
                @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Addresses.Count; i++)
                {
                <div class="addressRow">
                    @Html.DropDownList("Adresses[" + i + "].Type", Model.Addresses[i].AddressTypeSelectListItems, new { @class = "addressType form-control" })
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.Addresses[i].PostalCode, new { placeholder = "Почтовый индекс", @class = "addressPostalCode form-control" })
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.Addresses[i].Town, new { placeholder = "Город", @class = "addressTown form-control" })
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.Addresses[i].Street1, new { placeholder = "Улица", @class = "addressStreet1 form-control" })
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.Addresses[i].Street2, new { placeholder = "Номер дома или квартиры", @class = "addressStreet2 form-control" })
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remRowAddress"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>Удалить</a>
                </div>
                }
            </div>
            <p>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="addRowAddress"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>Добавить Адрес</a>
            </p>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Addresses, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Создать" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $(".addRowPhone").click(function () {

                var rowCount = $('.phoneRow').length;
                $("#phoneList").append('<div class="phoneRow"><select name="Phones[' + rowCount + '].Type" class="phoneType form-control">@foreach (var item in new Phone().PhoneTypeSelectListItems){<option value="@item.Value">@item.Text</option>}</select><input type="text" name="Phones[' + rowCount + '].Value" class="phoneNumber form-control" placeholder="Номер телефона" /><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remRowPhone"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>Удалить</a></div>');
            });

            $("#phoneList").on('click', '.remRowPhone', function () {

                $(this).closest('.phoneRow').remove();

                $('.phoneType').each(function (index) {
                    $(this).attr('name', 'Phones[' + index + '].Type');
                });

                $('.phoneNumber').each(function (index) {
                    $(this).attr('name', 'Phones[' + index + '].Value');
                });
            });

            $(".addRowEmail").click(function () {

                var rowCount = $('.emailRow').length;
                $("#emailList").append('<div class="emailRow"><select name="Emails[' + rowCount + '].Type" class="emailType form-control">@foreach (var item in new Email().EmailTypeSelectListItems){<option value="@item.Value">@item.Text</option>}</select><input type="text" name="Emails[' + rowCount + '].Value" class="emailValue form-control" placeholder="Электропочта" /><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remRowEmail"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>Удалить</a></div>');
            });

            $("#emailList").on('click', '.remRowEmail', function () {

                $(this).closest('.emailRow').remove();

                $('.emailType').each(function (index) {
                    $(this).attr('name', 'Emails[' + index + '].Type');
                });

                $('.emailValue').each(function (index) {
                    $(this).attr('name', 'Emails[' + index + '].Value');
                });
            });

            $(".addRowAddress").click(function () {

                var rowCount = $('.addressRow').length;
                $("#addressList").append('<div class="addreaaRow"><select name="Addresses[' + rowCount + '].Type" class="addressType form-control">@foreach (var item in new Address().AddressTypeSelectListItems){<option value="@item.Value">@item.Text</option>}</select><input type="text" name="Addresses[' + rowCount + '].postalCode" class="addressPostalCode form-control" placeholder="Почтовый индекс" /><input type="text" name="Addresses[' + rowCount + '].Town" class="addressTown form-control" placeholder="Город" /><input type="text" name="Addresses[' + rowCount + '].Street1" class="addressStreet1 form-control" placeholder="Улица" /><input type="text" name="Addresses[' + rowCount + '].Street2" class="addressStreet2 form-control" placeholder="Номер дома или квартиры" /><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remRowAddress"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>Удалить</a></div>');
            });

            $("#addressList").on('click', '.remRowAddress', function () {

                $(this).closest('.addressRow').remove();

                $('.addressType').each(function (index) {
                    $(this).attr('name', 'Addresses[' + index + '].Type');
                });

                $('.addressPostalCode').each(function (index) {
                    $(this).attr('name', 'Addresses[' + index + '].PostalCode');
                });

                $('.addressTown').each(function (index) {
                    $(this).attr('name', 'Addresses[' + index + '].Town');
                });

                $('.addressStreet1').each(function (index) {
                    $(this).attr('name', 'Addresses[' + index + '].Street1');
                });

                $('.addressStreet2').each(function (index) {
                    $(this).attr('name', 'Addresses[' + index + '].Street2');
                });
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: то есть нужно чтобы поле было изначально, но была возможность добавить его дубли?

Comment: У вас в razor секциях цикл идет до Count соответствующего свойства модели, который очевидно изначально равен нулю и в цикл вход не происходит.

Comment: да, нужно чтобы поле было изначально. В цикл не входит скорее всего, т.к. свойство `IList` пустое изначально. Как это исправить? Если произвожу изменения значений в операторе цикла, то выдает ошибку System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: "Индекс за пределами диапазона. Индекс должен быть положительным числом, а его размер не должен превышать размер коллекции.
Имя параметра: index"

Comment: Инициализируйте значениями по умолчанию соответствующие свойства в конструкторе модели.

Comment: это как? если я задаю в явном виде с индексом `[0]`, то вываливается в ошибку. Как должен выглядеть блок?

Comment: В конструктор модели добавьте строки вида Phones = new List<Phone> { new Phone(); };

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавил в модель конструкцию и все заработало:

```
    public Customer()
    {
        this.Addresses = new List<Address>();
        this.Phones = new List<Phone>();
        this.Emails = new List<Email>();
        this.ProfileUpdates = new List<ProfileUpdate>();
    }
```